# Login Password Keeps Getting Error PHP, PDO, Salt

Tags: php, pdo, authentication

```
<?php
require_once "pdo.php";
session_start();

// Redirect to index.php if use clicks cancel button
if ( isset($_POST['cancel'] ) ) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    return;
}

// salt and hash
$salt = 'XyZzy12*_';

// Check to see if we have some POST data, if we do process it
if ( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {

    // Check for email and password
    if ( strlen($_POST['email']) < 1 || strlen($_POST['pass']) < 1 ) {
        //$failure = "Email and password are required";
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email and password are required";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;

    // Check for at-sign in email
    } elseif (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Email must have an at-sign (@)";
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;

    } else {

        //All looks good, so redirect to index.php
        $check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);
        if ( $check == true) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['email'];
            error_log("Login success ".$_POST['email']);
            header("Location: index.php");
            return;
        } else {
            //Else redirect to the login page
            $_SESSION['error'] = "Incorrect Password";
            error_log("Login fail ".$_POST['email']." $check");
            header("Location: login.php");
            return;

        }
    }
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php require_once "bootstrap.php"; ?>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <br /><br />

        <?php

        // Message View of Errors
        if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) ) {
            echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($_SESSION['error'])."</p>\n");
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
        }

        ?>

        <h1>Please Log In</h1>

        <form method="POST">
            <label for="name">Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="name"><br/>
            <label for="id_1723">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
            <input type="submit" onclick="return doValidate();" value="Log In">
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
        </form>
```

Hi everyone, I'm learning PHP in a class, and I'm stuck on understanding what this code actually means. We were required to remove the $stored_hash that was once in the login.php file. Currently, we just have the $salt (line 12).

With this change, line 34 is confusing me. When I change $stored_hash to just $salt, I cannot get my login to work. It always says 'incorrect password' of which I don't even know where this is coming from.

Can anyone help explain line 12 and 34? I simply want the password to match the salt so the user can login. Any help is appreciated to a newbie like me, thanks.

Comment: A hash is a one way encryption algorithm, all the salt does is make it slightly harder to reverse engineer and guess a users password if you have access to the database.  Typically you store the hashes version of the users password in the database then take the hash of what they enter to see if it's the same.  If it is then the password is correct, if not then it's the wrong password.  Key to remember here is a hash as long as it uses same salt everytime will always create the same hash for a given string everytime without fail

Comment: post code as text, not a picture

Comment: The issue here is you are not saving the hash anywhere to a database or session key

Comment: a fixed salt is rather a bad idea.

Comment: Without that you can't check if the post of the pass when md5'ed with the salt is the same as the hash in the database for the user

Comment: any class that suggests md5 should be walked out off. its rubish

Comment: @nogad This code is the code provided by this class. This is not my start or method. Just trying to get through the assignment. :/

Comment: `$check = hash('md5', $salt.$_POST['pass']);` hash returns a string, not true or false. you would fist hash the posted password then compare it to a stored hash - you not doing the latter

Comment: use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` instead

Comment: I wish you could get your instructor to log on to Stack Overflow. If teachers and professors are not talking about proper security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later.